# Prevent accidental sequential command from running in terminal

Tags: unix, terminal

Something that happens occasionally is that I will be running a long-running python script or other command in the terminal and accidentally issue another command to that terminal (this is easy to do via the run button in VSCode, for example). The problem is that now when the first command ends something else will start running immediately after, and I would like to cancel this queued-up command.

Is there a way to stop this without killing the current script/command that's running?

FYI, I'm using Linux Mint with gnome-terminal.